# Converting SMS number to double (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to convert an SMS to double. I'm creating a monitoring system where values like "45.2" are sent to another modem.

I would like to convert 45.2 (which I think is string initially and placed in a textbox) to double so I can do comparison upon receiving it.

I have tried this but got errors:

```
Dim strMeasurement As String = txtMessage.Text.Trim
Dim dblMeasurement As Double = CDbl(strMeasurement)
```

Thanks.

Comment: What error are you getting? The code is correct (as in, it compiles and will yield *some* result … it may be the wrong result depending on language settings).

Comment: It works now, I used Double.TryParse()

Comment: Programming without understanding is [cargo cult](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_science). You should try to find and understand the *cause* of the error, not just use a solution that “fixes” the problem (for the time being!) without understanding what caused it and how to prevent it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Double.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw.aspx) instead

Answer (score 0):

as rahul said:
use

```
Double.tryParse(stringvalue, doublevalueTofill)
```

it returns a true if successful otherwise false.